# Getting access to a user's github data without Oauth

Tags: javascript, meteor, github, oauth

Would it be possible to embed a user's github profile (repos contributed to. etc etc) to a site without Oauth?

I do not want the user to sign in with his github profile (would prefer gmail/facebook for various reasons). But providing a option for the user to integrate his github stats would be helpful.

I'm trying to incorporate the above in a meteor project.

Thanks,
KJ

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure.

You can do get requests to urls like:

GET https://api.github.com/users/benlorantfy

GET https://api.github.com/users/benlorantfy/repos

The github API documentation is here: https://developer.github.com/v3/

You'll only be able to get public information though, you'll have to use Oauth to get private repo information.